# Postfix: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found

Tags: postfix-mta, smtp-auth

I configured postfix to send mail through a microsoft exchange server with SMTP authentication and TLS. In the log of the emails I see this error:

```
postfix / smtp [ 11191 ] : warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
postfix / smtp [ 11191 ] : B5BEB22019E : <my@mydomain.it> to = , relay = my.relay.host , delay = 0:07 , delays = 0.04/0.02/0.01/0 , dsn
= 4.7.0 , status = deferred ( SASL authentication failed , can not authenticate to server my.relay.host no mechanism available )
```

The postfix configuration is the default one , I added these lines:

```
relayhost = my.relay.host
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash :/ etc / postfix / sasl_passwd
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

The libraries cyrus -sasl and cyrus -sasl -devel cyrus- sasl- ntlm are installed , if I do a telnet to the server microsoft get:

```
220 my.relay.host Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, November 27 2013 10:20:40 +0100
ehlo
250 - MY.RELAY.HOST Hello [ XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ]
250 -SIZE 10485760
250-PIPELINING
250 - DSN
250 - ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 -AUTH LOGIN
250 - 8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
```

The administrator of the relay server tells me that authentication is NTLM , any ideas?

Thanks Stefano